# In drupal7, how can i use varibles when exporting configuration using features and strongarm modules?

Tags: drupal-7, simplesamlphp

I am working on a drupal7 site.

1. In Dev, I have enabled and configured simplesamlphp_auth module.
2. I used features and strongarm to export the configuration to code.
3. The downloaded feature contain:

   - myfeature_sso.features.defaultconfig.inc
   - myfeature_sso.info
   - myfeature_sso.module
4. The .inc file contains the configuration values I had put in (admin/config/people/simplesamlphp_auth) correctly
5. Now, in a few places, I want to replace the hard coded values with variables that change based on the environment. I set the variables at the top of .inc file using variable_get $office_ou = variable_get('office_ou', NULL); ...and . A quick example is $base_url below:

   $strongarm = new stdClass();
   $strongarm->disabled = FALSE;
   $strongarm->api_version = 1;
   $strongarm->name = 'simplesamlphp_auth_logoutgotourl';
   $strongarm->value = $base_url ;
   $export['simplesamlphp_auth_logoutgotourl'] = $strongarm;
6. When I DPM these variables, they display correct values.
7. But on a fresh install when I enable myfeature_sso module the value of variables are missing.

[missing value from $base_url variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYBAA.png)

Can you please point me in the right direction?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

1. when in features ui, do not add fields relevant to simplesamle to the defaultconfig section. if you have any there remove them.
2. add fields relevant to simplesaml to storongarm section
3. export the feature
4. in *your_feature_name*.strongarm.inc add any additional php code to function *your_feature_name*_strongarm()
5. done